# How to show my div panel in full screen HTML5 video player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I'm creating my own HTML5 video player controllers interface. I have created a div and coloured it blue and shaped it as a block. It is able to follow the video player's size and window's size. But it is not being shown when the video player is in Full Screen Mode. Please help me show the div `controls` in full screen mode. My code is below.

Note that the `FULL SCREEN` Button does not work in stack overflow. But it works on my website.

The screen shot of `The outcome I Get:` contains additional black coloured space on top and bottom of the player. The video also consists white coloured space left and right of the video/player.

My Code:

```css
#video_player {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
 
/*
THIS CAUSES THE FULL SCREEN BUTTON TO HIDE
#video_player 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
*/

#controls {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100px;
    background-color:#55b2ff;
}

#video_player_box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video_player_box">
        <video video-player controls id="video_player" src="http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1280x720_60fps_6000k.mp4"></video>
        <div id="controls">
        </div>
    </div><p>
    <button id="full_screen">FULL SCREEN</button>
    <script>
        var video_player = document.querySelector('#video_player_box');
        var button = document.getElementById("full_screen");
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if(video_player.requestFullScreen){
                video_player.requestFullScreen();
            } else if(video_player.webkitRequestFullScreen){
                video_player.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            } else if(video_player.mozRequestFullScreen){
                video_player.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screen Shots:

How I want the video and the player to cover the screen (with the div panel):

[image]

The outcome I Get:

[image]

Comment: "*Note that the FULL SCREEN Button does not work in stack overflow*". We can't possibly know what the problem is without being able to replicate it. Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cannot fix the problem of full screen not working in stack overflow. I just expect someone to use online shell and use my code to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might request Fullscreen on your `video_player_box` container.
So replace `var video_player = document.querySelector('[video-player]');`
 with `var video_player = document.querySelector('#video_player_box');`
and update your css (see the snippet below):

```css
#video_player {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#controls {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6.5%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color:#55b2ff;
}

#video_player_box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
}


#video_player_box:-moz-full-screen {height:100%}
#video_player_box:-webkit-full-screen {height:100%}
#video_player_box:-ms-fullscreen {height:100%}
#video_player_box:fullscreen {height:100%}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video_player_box">
        <video video-player controls id="video_player" src="http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1280x720_60fps_6000k.mp4"></video>
        <div id="controls">
            <!--CONTROLLERS WILL BE HERE-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><button id="full_screen">FULL SCREEN</button>
    <script>
        var video_player = document.querySelector('#video_player_box');
        var button = document.getElementById("full_screen");
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if(video_player.requestFullScreen){
             video_player.requestFullScreen();
            } else if(video_player.webkitRequestFullScreen){
             video_player.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            } else if(video_player.mozRequestFullScreen){
             video_player.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But in full screen mode, the video player does not fill the entire screen.

Comment: Yes. Does it fill the screen for you?

Comment: Yes of course. You can also try `#video_player {position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;}` instead of what you have now.

Comment: now the player fills the screen and hides the full screen button

Comment: Well, I tested it in Chrome and FF, and the posted answer works fine. And you can even discard my previous comment. Could you please make sure that you copy-pasted the code carefully?

Comment: I have updated the question with new code, screenshots and a small description of the screenshot above

Comment: @Aman, I've updated my answer with CSS 
`#video_player_box:-moz-full-screen {height:100%}`
`#video_player_box:-webkit-full-screen {height:100%}`
`#video_player_box:-ms-fullscreen {height:100%}`
`#video_player_box:fullscreen {height:100%}` to set the height in fullscreen mode explicitly.